# deep copy fires another function - python

Tags: python

What I want to happen is anytime I use deep copy on my class 'Node' that it runs the original method for deepCopy and then assigns a new UID to the node. This currently hits a recursion limit. I'm using deepCopy because my class object will expand to contain lists and dictionaries.

```
import copy
import uuid

# Classes
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        _new = (copy.deepcopy(self, memo))
        _new.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )
        return _new

class Truck(Node):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        super(Truck, self).__init__(name=name)


old_truck = Truck( name="Tonka Truck")
new_truck = copy.deepcopy( old_truck )

print old_truck.uid
print new_truck.uid
```

---

attempted solution seems to work alright

```
import copy
import uuid

# Classes
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )

    def copy_node(self):
        new_node = copy.deepcopy( self )
        new_node.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )
        return new_node

class Truck(Node):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        super(Truck, self).__init__(name=name)


old_truck = Truck( name="Tonka Truck")
new_truck = old_truck.copy_node()

print old_truck.uid
print new_truck.uid
```

Comment: What do you expect the nested deepcopy to do?  Just copy the name?

Comment: There will eventually be more attributes on the object. such as lists and dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the call to `deepcopy` that you have, call the parent directly:

```
_new = super(Node, self).__deepcopy__(memo)
```

You'll still need to copy the other members of your class individually.